# android studio gradle refresh failed (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am receiving following error in android studio gradle

> Error:C:\Users\Subash.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\asLocalRepo16_1ny8gqikcqanmkspcmvyfsub7\InitScript\initscript\cache.properties
>   (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: set the directory chmod 777 and gradle clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right this problem can be solved with a simple correction of the path of the file that contains the correct version of gradle.

You can find it in Android Studio -> Preferences -> Gradle -> service directory path.

You must find the correct version of gradle to run smoothly. I have [gradle-2.4-rc-1].

I hope this can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: There is no preferences

Comment: I am using Android Studio for Mac.